# TYPO3 how to set specific view

Tags: typo3, extbase

How to set specific view in my extension?

`$this->view->assign('example', $example);`  -  it means that view path must fit with controller and action names. I need to set specific views with another path and name! Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use $this->view->setTemplatePathAndFilename('path/to/your/template.html'); to set a custom view.

Comment: I just wanted to add that as far as possible you should not override the expected template paths. Among other things, resolving of partials and layouts still happens based on defined root paths, not explicitly defined template names. But in a pinch the suggestion from Wouter can be used. Additional caveat: if the expected template file does not exist you will get an error even if you attempt to override the file this way. The reason is the resolving of that file gets done *before* the controller even processes the request; if not found, no processing will happen.

Comment: @ClausDue As you said this is not the best way to solve this. What if I want to use the same controller action in 2 different templates/views. Would this be the best way, or is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: Not sure if I understand that question completely, but usually if you want to "use the same controller action in two views" that implies you want to change the *layout* rather than the *action*. There are several ways to achieve this - to name a few: dynamic layout names, dynamic layout overrides based on action, different view init in action initialise method, dynamically wrapping output with f:render + contentAs, and the suggestion Wouter gave above (except replacing the layout path and filename). Which one you want completely depends on your exact use case and requires careful thought.